# How to make textBox and button side by side?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a project and I need to make a search section but I have a problem. I want to make search button side by side with textBox but I couldn't figure it out how to do it. How can I make them side by side ?

[image: This is how it looks like]

[image: And here it is my code]

Comment: Hi! Please Upload code

Comment: `display: inline-block` on both could suffice by the way... but there are better approaches

Comment: If you post images of code, please also copy/paste or type the actual code directly into the post as text (within a code block). [Code in images cannot be copied to reproduce the issue](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273). Posts in which code is only included in images are likely to be closed for not having enough details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```html
display: flex;
```

this should put all elements inside the div next to eachother

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="myDiv">
<input/>
<input/>
</div>
```

```css
#myDiv {
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: row;
}
```